# What are the difference between the gems bundle and bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've noticed that both of these work:

```
gem install bundle
```

and

```
gem install bundler
```

What is the difference?

`bundle` is just an empty gem with `bundler` as dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [the page for bundle](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundle), it's sort of poor man's alias. Someone realized that it will be a [frequent mistake](https://github.com/will/bundle#has-this-ever-happened-to-you). Installing `bundle` simply installs `bundler`.

Good thing, imagine if someone actually created a completely separate gem, called *bundle*.

Answer (score 1):

No difference as such. They are almost same. In fact, **bundle** is an alias for **bundler**.

Comment: The difference is not completely non-existent. For example if you install bundle, you will have bundler installed as well, while the opposite is not the case.